# Using Pinescript flags/alerts in conditional statements for scoring strategy

Tags: pine-script

reference to Stochastic 'Flag/Alert':
[image: reference to Stochastic 'Flag/Alert']

My question relates to a strategy I am working on that utilizes multiple indicators, most being custom built. The main use of the indicators come from the basic flags (plot shapes)/ alerts, being either red or green. My question relates to scoring various checks in my trade check list.

Here's an example of how the scoring would work...

```
SMAPoints = (sma > sma[1] ? 5 : 0)
```

For the picture I included, it displays stochastic full. I was wondering if I had to code the crossover from my variables or if whenever the indicator prints a green 'flag' it will assign a point to the variable (ie: StochPoints) which would later be tallied up under TotalPoints.

Here is the source code for that indicator:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch")
periodK = input(10, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(10, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(10, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)
plot(k, title="%K", color=color.blue)
plot(d, title="%D", color=color.orange)
h0 = hline(80)
h1 = hline(20)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.purple, transp=75)
plotshape(crossunder(k, d) ? d + 5 : na, color=color.red, location=location.absolute, style=shape.arrowdown)
plotshape(crossover(k, d) ? d - 5 : na, color=color.green, location=location.absolute, style=shape.arrowup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to assemble your different indicators into one code base if you want to tally an aggregate value for their individual conditions.

Once that's done, you will need to assign your conditions' values to intermediary variables which you can then use to derive a composite numerical value based on those conditions. You will also use those same stored conditions in your `plotshape()` calls to control their logic instead of using the conditions literally in there as you do now.

See how it's done in my [Delta Volume Candles](https://www.tradingview.com/script/h0yZPTiS-Delta-Volume-Candles-LucF/) indicator where I calculate the *Marker Bias*. So I'm using the aggregate of other marker conditions to generate a new signal.

[image]

Comment: Gotcha! That makes a lot more sense! Thank you for your help!